# Magento 2: Don't need delivery address

Tags: magento2, checkout, delivery

Each of my products can be sent to a recipient (they're gift products), so I have address fields (just text input fields – `custom options`) in which the purchaser would add the address of the person to whom they'd like to post the product. As a customer may by two or three products, with each one being posted to a different person, I have no need for the purchaser on my store to enter their delivery address once they go to the checkout page.

Is there a way for me to disable M2 from asking for the customer's delivery address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, quite simple: Create your gifts as virtual products. If the cart contains only virtual or downloadable items, you will not have to enter any shipping address at checkout.

NOTE: Using virtual products will skip the shipping address during checkout. It will also skip the shipping method, and the associated shipping cost. Removing the shipping address step for normal simple products (without affecting the shipping method or cost) would be much, much more complicated.

## Creating a virtual product

You can create a virtual product by going to `Admin > Products > Catalog`, clicking the arrow on the 'Add Product' button, and clicking 'Virtual Product'.

[image: Virtual product option]

You can also change an existing simple product to virtual by editing it and finding the 'Weight' attribute under General settings. Change 'Does this have a weight?' from Yes to No.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rayan Hoerr it's working for me ... happy coding